# ReactJS Simple Component Not Shown

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a small search bar onto my website, but what I see is that it is still existing in the website, but its size becomes 0x0, and I can't find anything wrong with my ES6 code. Can someone debug for me please?

[image: It only shows that it exists in the html, but not actually showing anything.]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>React-Redux-Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import searchBar from './components/searchBar'
const youtubeAPIKey = '...'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <searchBar />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

searchBar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class searchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {term: ''}
  }
  render() {
    return <input onChange={event => console.log(event.target.value)}/>
  }
}

export default searchBar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my boss actually found it out, it's the problem about CAPITALIZING the variable names. After I cap the first letter of the variable names things are working again...

Comment: What you are referring to as variable name is actually the Component name, isn't it? You have to use Pascal Case for Component names.

Answer (score 2):

First of, you have defined your component as `<searchBar\>`. I guess React is not able to see it as JSX Component and is embedding it as a plain html tag instead, as evidenced by the `<searchbar\>` tag seen in Elements tab of chrome.

I think what you need is, to figure out why react is not able see searchBar as a JSX component. I hope this leads you to the right direction.

Comment: Emmm that sounds like a good way to go, but I'm really new to React that I have no idea where would it make the mistake

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your search bar code works fine. Check your CSS to make sure that your body has a size.

Comment: My css is empty, only Bootstrap should be shown right now

Comment: try commenting the bootstrap styles out and add in your own style. Something that gives the body width. html, body{ 
  width:100%;
}

Comment: It still doesn't work, and it's actually becoming 0x0. So I'm thinking it might be something else instead of css...